# Why <br> tag was not parsed inside custom HTMLColumn in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Ok, I have a HTML column which should parse any `TextCell` that contain html tag into HTML value:

```java
public class HTMLColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>{
    public HTMLColumn(){
          super(new ClickableTextCell(){
            public void render(Context context, 
                   SafeHtml value, 
                   SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
            {
                //String text="";
                if(value!=null){
                    //text=value.asString();
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div>");
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<b>"+value.asString()+"</b>");
                    sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
                }

            }   
       });
    }
}
```

ok, when testing with the text contain `car<br>bike`, i can see the whole text got bold so  `sb.appendHtmlConstant` seem to be ok, but it did not make the `bike` to be in new line. It rendered the text like this: bold `car<br>bike`.

That mean `<br>` was not parsed.

Is this the css problem or something happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `value` (the `SafeHtml` passed in the `render` method) is not what you want.

When the string that you want to insert is parsed in order to become a `SafeHtml` it needs to be done like below if you trust the `String`.

```java
SafeHtml safeHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(value);
```

I think a way to do this is by creating your `ClickableTextCell` with your own implementation of `SafeHtmlRenderer`.

```java
ClickableTextCell cell = new ClickableTextCell(new SafeHtmlRenderer<String>(){

    SafeHtml render(String object){
       return SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(object);
    }

    void render(String object, SafeHtmlBuilder builder){
        builder.appendHtmlConstant(object);
    }

});
```